# Spring REST webservice with JSON param to be consumed using Jquery AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring

I am trying to learn Spring Framework for creating RESTful web service for my future projects. So far I have tried using GET and consume it with no problem using a simple Ajax request. I have also tried using query strings to input parameters.

As of now I am trying to create an endpoint that receives a POST request. I've been researching for some days now but to no avail (some tuts are too complicated for a beginner like me).

Here is my simple code:

Java Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String testString(String jsonString)
{
        System.out.println(jsonString);
        return jsonString;
}
```

Ajax

```
  var data = {"name":"John Doe"}
  $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/test",
              method:"POST",
              data:data,
              dataType:'text',
              success: function( data ) {
                 alert(data);                                 
              },
              error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                  alert("Error:" + errorThrown + status);
              }
      });
```

I have tried debugging tomcat and it seems like I am not passing any value on the testString. Do I need to add something on my java code?

Comment: what is the issue? is `jsonString` null? take a look at `@RequestBody`

Comment: `data:{jsonString:data},` change to this also set a valid `contentType:'application/json'`

Comment: Yes jsonString is always null. I've also tried changing the name into jsonString still no proper response

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` only maps your method to some url.
To access data you need `@RequestParam` annotation to get data, eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String testString(@RequestParam("name") String jsonString)
{
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}
```

Look at [this](http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable) manual for more examples.

Comment: So I can use @RequestParam without the query strings?

Comment: `@RequestParam` stores variables, that came in request. Either `GET` and `POST`. You're, also can use `@PathVariable`. Refer to manuals.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing data into body from your ajax request, so you need to retrieve from the

> @RequestBody

Add this annotation before the arguments like this way;

```
public String testString(@RequestBody String jsonString) {
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}
```

And you are done :)